# Is there away to update project all project references in one go?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

I have just picked up a project which refers to the asp.net 2.0 framework. I'm currently using v4.

Is there a way of updating all the Microsoft references from 2.0 to 4.0 in one go?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the option under properties tab for the solution.